# Remove an uncertain chunk of a string (a URL)

Tags: php, string, anchor, strip

I have a JSON array like this:

```
[
    {
        "title": " Bones of the Hills <a href="/series/44108-conqueror" class="greyText">(Conqueror #3) </a>",
        "author": "Conn Iggulden",
        "format": "Hardcover",
        "pages": "518",
        "rating": "4.29",
        "image": "http://d.gr-assets.com/books/1347616868l/3276637.jpg"
    }
]
```

Sometimes, (not always) the title string has a link in it. How can I remove the link and everything in it? I don't even want the text inside the anchor. I want to end up with JUST "Bones of the Hills" as the title. How can I do this in php? I have googled loads, but nothing seemed to work.

Comment: If link is using html tags like <a href> than You can use php builtin function strip_tags() on title, it will remove all html elements from title including link

Comment: is this json array created in php  or javascript side ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php built in function strip_tags() on title, it will remove all html elements from title including link

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip_tag() function to avoid this error

```
 $str='[{"title": " Bones of the Hills <a href="/series/44108-conqueror" class="greyText">(Conqueror #3) </a>","author": "Conn Iggulden","format": "Hardcover",';
        $str.='"pages": "518","rating": "4.29","image": "http://d.gr-assets.com/books/1347616868l/3276637.jpg"}]';
  echo      $str2=strip_tags($str);
  $array=json_decode($str2);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: I think your answer is wrong look at this strip_tags — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string , so your code won't give you the expected results , check the manual - > http://php.net/strip_tags

Answer (score 0):

first of all your json array is incorrect , check this

```
[
    {
        "title": " "title": " Bones of the Hills <a href=\\"/series/44108-conqueror\\" class=\\"test\\">(Conqueror #3) </a>",
        "author": "Conn Iggulden",
        "format": "Hardcover",
        "pages": "518",
        "rating": "4.29",
        "image": "http://d.gr-assets.com/books/1347616868l/3276637.jpg"
    }
]
```

use `"title": " Bones of the Hills <a href=\\"/series/44108-conqueror\\" class=\\"test\\">(Conqueror #3) </a>"`

instead of

`<a href="/series/44108-conqueror" class="greyText"`

then

```
$arr = json_decode($json,true);
$arr['title'] = preg_replace("/<a.+?href.+?>.+?<\/a>/is","",$arr['title']);

var_dump($arr['title']);
```

now your title will be

```
string(20) " Bones of the Hills "
```

Comment: I cannot change the string. It is given to me so, I have no control over it.

Comment: @jeremys so without changing the string try my answer . :) starting from $arr = json_decode($json,true);